# How to include math mode in-line with the rest of the text

Tags: math-mode

How do I include math mode in-line with the rest of the text? Currently it is awkwardly standing out. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}  

 \section{Conclusions}
 To the credit of this work, few studies include control variables 
 such as gender, race, or age. In this study, it was found that 
 male CEOs are expected to earn less than female CEOs. With regards 
 to age, the coefficients on age and \[ \textrm{age}^2 \] show, as 
 expected, increasing then decreasing levels of compensation. 

\end{document}
```

[image: awkward!]

Comment: Have you tried inline math mode instead of display math mode? E.g, `...the coefficients on $\textrm{age}$ and $\textrm{age}^2$ show, as expected, ...`. Observe that `$` serves to both initiate and terminate inline math mode.

Comment: Or use \( ... \) instead of \[ ... \].

Comment: Not related to the problem, but don't load the same package more than once.

Comment: @IanThompson , which one(s) am I repeating?

Comment: @Mico , Bernard's response appears much quicker. Thanks though

Comment: @texmex --- booktabs, makecell and caption.

Comment: @IanThompson does it matter which I delete? For example, I see \usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}       as well as     \usepackage{caption}

Comment: @texmex --- Delete the first instance of `caption` to keep your document as it is. Note that the option `skip=1ex` makes the space between the caption and the figure (or table) a bit smaller than the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And why not simply `\textsuperscript`?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% replaces mtpro2, which is not installed on my system
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}

 \section{Conclusions}

    To the credit of this work, few studies
    include control variables such as gender, race, or age. In this study, it was found that male CEOs are expected to earn less than female CEOs. With regards to age, the coefficients on age and age\textsuperscript{2} show, as expected, increasing then decreasing levels of compensation.

\end{document}
```

[image]